# cannot modify array inside a function

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
protected function _changeArray(&$Products)
    {
        foreach($Products as $item)
        {
            Mage::log('Type: '.$item['attribute']);

            switch($item['shipping_attribute'])
            {
                case '0':
                    $item['is_cargo'] = 'no';
                    $item['is_bulky'] = 'no';
                    $item['is_firework'] = 'no';
                    Mage::log('assigned '.$item['attribute']);
                    break;
                case '1':
                    $item['is_cargo'] = 'yes';
                    $item['is_bulky'] = 'no';
                    $item['is_firework'] = 'no';
                    Mage::log('assigned '.$item['attribute']);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $item['is_cargo'] = 'no';
                    $item['is_bulky'] = 'yes';
                    $item['is_firework'] = 'no';
                    Mage::log('assigned '.$item['attribute']);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $item['is_cargo'] = 'no';
                    $item['is_bulky'] = 'no';
                    $item['is_firework'] = 'yes';
                    Mage::log('assigned '.$item['attribute']);
                    break;
            }
            Mage::log('"switch" finished!');
        }
    }
```

I am trying to change these elements of the `Products` array, depending on the value of another element of the array. What seems not to happen is they don't get changed... Everything always stays to `'no'` value. I know that the `'attribute'` value is different in a correct way and that the function goes through the `switch-cases` correctly, because of the testings that I am writing in the `log`.

I am printing the `Products` array after calling my function, and it is not changed. I thought it will work with passing by reference, but nope... I also tried with passing the array the normal way and returning it from the function - unsuccessful again.

What am I doing wrong or not doing enough ?

Oh, yeah, I also tried having the `switch-case` in the following way:

```
case '...':
    $Products['is_cargo'] = 'yes';
    $Products['is_bulky'] = 'no';
    $Products['is_firework'] = 'no';
    Mage::log('assigned '.$Products['attribute']);
    break;
```

nope again...

Comment: `foreach($Products as &$item)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set $item "by reference" in your `foreach` loop

```
foreach($Products as &$item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually do anything to the input array, except for reading them..

You need to change the input array, not the  $item array,  $item is only an extracted item.

So basically:

use:

```
 foreach($Products as $key => $item)
```

and change to:

```
$Products[$key]['is_cargo'] = 'no';
```

Ideally you do not use the function by reference, but return the output array from the function to the script

Added:

I would run it like this:

```
protected function _changeArray($Products)
{
    foreach($Products as $key => $product)
    {
        Mage::log('Type: '.$Products[$key]['attribute']);

        switch($Products[$key]['shipping_attribute'])
        {

            case '0':
                $Products[$key]['is_cargo'] = 'no';
                $Products[$key]['is_bulky'] = 'no';
                $Products[$key]['is_firework'] = 'no';
                break;
//etc
```

and do a return $products at the end of the function.

Call:

$data = _changeArray($data);